# How to wire cut ethernet cable that is weirdly-wired at ends?

Tags: networking, ethernet, rj-45

My mum cut ethernet cable (cat 5 or 5e) that connects my switch with main router. We plan on crimping the cut sides and coupling them.

I'm just not sure what the right wiring  for that is, as the router side is wired :

> wo o wb _ _ b _ _

and at my end :

> wb b wo _ _ o _ _

which does not correspond with any wiring standard I was able to find.

How to wire the cut ends of the ethernet cable?

EDIT: the photos of connectors

[router end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pJpA.jpg)

[my end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aldgW.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This is a Q&A community. That means you need to ask a specific question. Please include what research you have already done.

Comment: That is a crossover cable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable#Crossover_cable_pinouts

Comment: @CharlieRB Thank you. I thought I had asked my question? How to wire the cut ends of the ethernet cable? But maybe I wasn't clear enough? I will edit it in.| About the research ... beside trying to wire/crimple/couple the ends I don't know how I could do any research.

Comment: Why don't you include some pictures of said connectors.

Comment: Please use the [edit] feature to add this additional info to the question.

Comment: @CoscoTech I didn't think there would be seen anything more than what I said, but I will post them in a second if you think that helps.

Comment: @user4556274 yes, it seems so to my uninformed person, except with color mixed? But I have no idea if that changes/how it changes the wiring of the cut ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cable is cut in the middle and you want to attach it back together at the place of the cut it is very simple (regardless of wiring standard).

Simply crimp on a RJ45 connector in the same wiring order as 1 of the original ends. But make sure the use the SAME order on BOTH NEW connectors.
After that you can simply connect them using a normal straight through coupling plug.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to crimp both ends with a standard cat5 end and color code it the same so it's 1:1 and use a coupler.

I've seen people simply wire it together and use electrical marrets. It can work if your really in a pinch but you will have alot of random network issues (including random dropped packets and latency issuesetc.) if your moving any real data.

[https://www.amazon.com/RJ45-Ethernet-cable-connector-Almond/dp/B000BSLW8U](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BSLW8U)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the wire was cut in the middle and you're trying to splice it.  My suggestion is, don't.  Just get a new cable, it'll be much easier and save you headache in the long run.

Otherwise if the break is in the middle, just wire the same colors together.  The order of the wires in the plugs is where the magic happens.  So in your case wo->wo, o->o, wb->wb, b->b.

Comment: Getting 20 metres of the cable, and going to roof (and neighbors) to place it seems to me more troublesome than connecting two cables.

Comment: Splicing will work, but it sounds like it'll be exposed outdoors.  Eventually it will fail again and you'll be back at square one.